# Integrating ParamQuery Grid with MySQL DB and displaying query results by creating a JSON object - does not show the fetched records

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to integrate the Paramquery grid plugin (source: http://paramquery.com/) with MySQL DB - so that the fetched records from any table are displayed after pagination and sorting.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Step 1:  Fetch the data from MySQL table and convert the result set into JSON object

```
<?PHP
    include "connection.php";       // Sets up connectivity to MySQL database

    // Check if the table has at least one record.
    $query = "SELECT count(*) AS C FROM pr_vendor_list ";

    $result     =   mysql_query($query);
    $row    =   mysql_fetch_object($result);

    if ($row->C > 0)
     {
        // Fetch all records from the table.
        $query1 = "SELECT vendor_nm, addr_1, addr_2, city FROM pr_vendor_list  ";

        $result1    =   mysql_query($query1);
        $rows       =   array();


        while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) )
         {
           $rows[] = $row1;
         }
         // create JSON object
        $json_data  =    json_encode($rows);
        else
        {
              ; // Empty table - do something else
        }
```

?>

Step 2: After creating the JSON object I am trying to render the results in the aforesaid jQuery plugin:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<!--jQuery dependencies-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--PQ Grid files-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pqgrid.min.css" />
<script src="pqgrid.min.js"></script>
<!--PQ Grid Office theme-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/office/pqgrid.css" />

<script>
$(function () {

// Following commented block has the orginal data source inline

/*
var data = [[1, 'Exxon Mobil', '339,938.0', '36,130.0'],
[2, 'Wal-Mart Stores', '315,654.0', '11,231.0'],
[3, 'Royal Dutch Shell', '306,731.0', '25,311.0'],
[19, 'Crédit Agricole', '110,764.6', '7,434.3'],
[20, 'American Intl. Group', '108,905.0', '10,477.0']];
*/

var data = <?PHP echo $json_data;?>;
var obj = { width: 800, height: 400, title: "Registered Vendors" };

obj.colModel = 
[
{ title: "Vendor Name", width: 200, dataType: "string" },
{ title: "Address 1", width: 200, dataType: "string" },
{ title: "Address 2", width: 200, dataType: "string", align: "center" },
{ title: "City", width: 200, dataType: "string", align: "center"}
];

obj.dataModel = 
{ 
data: data ,
sorting: "local",
paging: "local",
dataType: "JSON",
method: "GET",
curPage: 1,
rPP: 20,
sortIndx: 0,
sortDir: "up",
rPPOptions: [5, 10, 15, 100, 1000]
};

var $grid = $("#grid_parts").pqGrid(obj);
$("#grid_parts_topVisible").change(function (evt) {
//alert("");
$grid.pqGrid("option", "topVisible", $(this).is(":checked"));
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "topVisible"));
$("#grid_parts_bottomVisible").change(function (evt) {
//alert("");
$grid.pqGrid("option", "bottomVisible", $(this).is(":checked"));
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "bottomVisible"));
$("#grid_parts_columnBorders").change(function (evt) {
//alert("");
$grid.pqGrid("option", "columnBorders", $(this).is(":checked"));
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "columnBorders"));
$("#grid_parts_rowBorders").change(function (evt) {
//alert("");
$grid.pqGrid("option", "rowBorders", $(this).is(":checked"));
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "rowBorders"));
$("#grid_parts_oddRowsHighlight").change(function (evt) {
//alert("");
$grid.pqGrid("option", "oddRowsHighlight", $(this).is(":checked"));
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "oddRowsHighlight"));
$("#grid_parts_numberCell").change(function (evt) {
//alert("");
$grid.pqGrid("option", "numberCell", $(this).is(":checked"));
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "numberCell"));

$("#grid_parts_autoHeight").change(function (evt) {
//alert("");
$grid.pqGrid("option", "flexHeight", $(this).is(":checked"));
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "flexHeight"));

$("#grid_parts_autoWidth").change(function (evt) {
//alert("");
$grid.pqGrid("option", "flexWidth", $(this).is(":checked"));
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "flexWidth"));

$("#grid_parts_horizontal").change(function (evt) {
//alert("");
$grid.pqGrid("option", "scrollModel", { horizontal: $(this).is(":checked") });
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "scrollModel.horizontal"));

$("#grid_parts_resizable").change(function (evt) {
//alert("");
$grid.pqGrid("option", "resizable", $(this).is(":checked"));
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "resizable"));

$("#grid_parts_paging").change(function (evt) {
var paging="";
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
paging = "local";
}
$grid.pqGrid("option", "dataModel.paging", paging);
}).attr("checked", ($grid.pqGrid("option", "dataModel.paging")=="local")?true:false);

$("#grid_parts_roundCorners").change(function (evt) {
$grid.pqGrid("option", "roundCorners", $(this).is(":checked"));
}).attr("checked", $grid.pqGrid("option", "roundCorners"));

//
$( "#grid_parts" ).pqGrid( {numberCell:false} );

});     
</script>    
</head>

<body>
<center>
<div id="grid_parts" style="margin:10px;"></div>
<BR>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to see the created grid but no data is displayed there. All I see is the empty grid correctly displaying the total no of fetched records in the pagination bar.

========================================================================

Based on suggestions made by Harshitha I modified the code. Another observation I have is that if I am passing the value as an array object, the rendering happens as expected. However, if the var obj is initialized as JSON object, though the grid is rendered but not the rows corresponding to json data.

I am appending the latest code below with appropriate annotations.

```
    <?PHP
    include "connection.php";       // Sets up connectivity to MySQL database

    // Check if the table has at least one record.
    $query = "SELECT count(*) AS C FROM pr_vendor_list ";

    $result     =   mysql_query($query);
    $row    =   mysql_fetch_object($result);

    if ($row->C > 0)
    {
    // Fetch all records from the table.
    $query1 = "SELECT vendor_nm, addr_1, addr_2, city FROM pr_vendor_list  ";

    $result1    =   mysql_query($query1);
    $rows       =   array();


    while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) )
    {
    $rows[] = $row1;
    }
    // create JSON object
    $json_data  =    json_encode($rows);        // This var value will be used in HTML <script> section below to initialize the JS object
    }
    else
    {
    ; // Empty table - do something else
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <!--jQuery dependencies-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--PQ Grid files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pqgrid.min.css" />
    <script src="pqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <!--PQ Grid Office theme-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/office/pqgrid.css" />

    <script>
    $(function () { 

    /*
    var data = 
    [
    [1, 'Exxon Mobil', '339,938.0', '36,130.0'],
    [2, 'Wal-Mart Stores', '315,654.0', '11,231.0'],
    [3, 'Royal Dutch Shell', '306,731.0', '25,311.0'],
    [4, 'BP', '267,600.0', '22,341.0'],
    [5, 'General Motors', '192,604.0', '-10,567.0'],
    [6, 'Chevron', '189,481.0', '14,099.0'],
    [7, 'DaimlerChrysler', '186,106.3', '3,536.3'],
    [8, 'Toyota Motor', '185,805.0', '12,119.6'],
    [9, 'Ford Motor', '177,210.0', '2,024.0'],
    [10, 'ConocoPhillips', '166,683.0', '13,529.0'],
    [11, 'General Electric', '157,153.0', '16,353.0'],
    [12, 'Total', '152,360.7', '15,250.0'],
    [13, 'ING Group', '138,235.3', '8,958.9'],
    [14, 'Citigroup', '131,045.0', '24,589.0'],
    [15, 'AXA', '129,839.2', '5,186.5'],
    [16, 'Allianz', '121,406.0', '5,442.4'],
    [17, 'Volkswagen', '118,376.6', '1,391.7'],
    [18, 'Fortis', '112,351.4', '4,896.3'],
    [19, 'Crédit Agricole', '110,764.6', '7,434.3'],
    [20, 'American Intl. Group', '108,905.0', '10,477.0']
    ];
    */  

    var data = [
    { rank: 1, company: 'Exxon Mobil', revenues: '339,938.0', profits: '36,130.0' },
    { rank: 2, company: 'Wal-Mart Stores', revenues: '315,654.0', profits: '11,231.0' },
    { rank: 3, company: 'Royal Dutch Shell', revenues: '306,731.0', profits: '25,311.0' },
    { rank: 4, company: 'BP', revenues: '267,600.0', profits: '22,341.0' },
    { rank: 5, company: 'General Motors', revenues: '192,604.0', profits: '-10,567.0' },
    { rank: 6, company: 'Chevron', revenues: '189,481.0', profits: '14,099.0' },
    { rank: 7, company: 'DaimlerChrysler', revenues: '186,106.3', profits: '3,536.3' },
    { rank: 8, company: 'Toyota Motor', revenues: '185,805.0', profits: '12,119.6' },
    { rank: 9, company: 'Ford Motor', revenues: '177,210.0', profits: '2,024.0' },
    { rank: 10, company: 'ConocoPhillips', revenues: '166,683.0', profits: '13,529.0' },
    { rank: 11, company: 'General Electric', revenues: '157,153.0', profits: '16,353.0' },
    { rank: 12, company: 'Total', revenues: '152,360.7', profits: '15,250.0' },
    { rank: 13, company: 'ING Group', revenues: '138,235.3', profits: '8,958.9' },
    { rank: 14, company: 'Citigroup', revenues: '131,045.0', profits: '24,589.0' },
    { rank: 15, company: 'AXA', revenues: '129,839.2', profits: '5,186.5' },
    { rank: 16, company: 'Allianz', revenues: '121,406.0', profits: '5,442.4' },
    { rank: 17, company: 'Volkswagen', revenues: '118,376.6', profits: '1,391.7' },
    { rank: 18, company: 'Fortis', revenues: '112,351.4', profits: '4,896.3' },
    { rank: 19, company: 'Crédit Agricole', revenues: '110,764.6', profits: '7,434.3' },
    { rank: 20, company: 'American Intl. Group', revenues: '108,905.0', profits: '10,477.0' }
    ];


    /*
    // This would be the code eventually to initialize the JS variable from PHP created JSON object

    var data = <?PHP echo $json_data;?>;

    */
    var obj = { width: 700, height: 400, title: "Grid From JSON data", flexHeight: true };
    obj.colModel = 
    [
    { title: "Rank", width: 100, dataType: "integer", dataIndex: "rank"  },
    { title: "Company", width: 200, dataType: "string", dataIndex: "company"  },
    { title: "Revenues ($ millions)", width: 150, dataType: "float" , dataIndex: "revenues" },
    { title: "Profits ($ millions)", width: 150, dataType: "float", dataIndex: "profits" }
    ];

    obj.dataModel = 
    { 
    data: data ,
    sorting: "local",
    paging: "local",
    dataType: "JSON",
    method: "GET",
    curPage: 1,
    rPP: 20,
    sortIndx: 0,
    sortDir: "up",
    rPPOptions: [5, 10, 15, 100, 1000]
    };

    $("#grid_sorted").pqGrid(obj);

    });

    </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <div id="grid_sorted" style="margin:100px;"></div>  <!-- renders the grid here -->
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include dataIndx in your colModel

Place your php code in the beginning of your page.
Then in the script part use

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var data = <?PHP echo 'var data ='.$json_data; ?>
obj = { width: 800, height: 400, title: "Registered Vendors" };
obj.colModel = 
[
{ title: "Vendor Name", width: 200, dataType: "string", dataIndx:"vendor_nm" },
{ title: "Address 1", width: 200, dataType: "string", dataIndx:"addr_1" },
{ title: "Address 2", width: 200, dataType: "string", align: "center", dataIndx:"addr_2"},
{ title: "City", width: 200, dataType: "string", align: "center", dataIndx:"city"}
];

});
```

place the remaining code as it is below from `obj.dataModel`

Comment: However, the I am still unable to render the grid, after making the suggested changes.....

Comment: what is the problem that your are facing? any errors in the console? This is working for me so it should work. check the console log and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here is how I was able to make it work (*I'll use your data as an example*) Not sure if this is still an issue for you

1. Create a PHP file that returns a JSON output, call it `json_sample.php`

```html
    <?php
    include "connection.php";

    // Check if the table has at least one record.
    $query = "SELECT count(*) AS C FROM pr_vendor_list ";

    $result     =   mysql_query($query);
    $row    =   mysql_fetch_object($result);

    if ($row->C > 0)
    {
    // Fetch all records from the table.
    $query1 = "SELECT vendor_nm, addr_1, addr_2, city FROM pr_vendor_list  ";

    $result1    =   mysql_query($query1);
    $rows       =   array();


    while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) )
    {
    $rows[] = $row1;
    }
    // create JSON object
    echo json_encode($rows);
    ?>
```

2. Create a `javascript` file that will use the json file to get your data, call it `sample_script.js`
3. Create your `index.php` file which will show your results.

```js
    $(function() {
      $.getJSON("sample_json.php", function(data) {
        var obj = {
          width: 700,
          height: 400,
          title: "Grid From JSON data",
          flexHeight: true
        };
        obj.colModel = [{
          title: "Rank",
          width: 100,
          dataType: "integer",
          dataIndex: "rank"
        }, {
          title: "Company",
          width: 200,
          dataType: "string",
          dataIndex: "company"
        }, {
          title: "Revenues ($ millions)",
          width: 150,
          dataType: "float",
          dataIndex: "revenues"
        }, {
          title: "Profits ($ millions)",
          width: 150,
          dataType: "float",
          dataIndex: "profits"
        }];

        obj.dataModel = {
          data: data,
          sorting: "local",
          paging: "local",
          dataType: "JSON",
          method: "GET",
          curPage: 1,
          rPP: 20,
          sortIndx: 0,
          sortDir: "up",
          rPPOptions: [5, 10, 15, 100, 1000]
        };

        $("#grid_json").pqGrid(obj);

      });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <titleSAmple Gird</title>
    <!--jQuery DEPENDENCIES-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <!-- FOR PQGRID -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/pqgrid.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/pqgrid_office.css" />

    <!--jQuery DEPENDENCIES-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FOR PQGRID -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/touch-punch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/pqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/sample_script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div id="grid_json" style="margin:100px;"></div>
    <!-- renders the grid here -->
</body>

</html>
```

This worked for me. Let me know if you have any questions.